# Using tables without ID field for GraphQL server for Relay

Tags: graphql, relay

I have a legacy SQL DB with tables that are not optimised for Relay Modern because non of the tables have a property

> id

I use **Sequelize** as an ORM and **express-graphql** as the GraphQl layer.

Sequelize Layer:

```
const STAFF = sequelize.define('staff', {
    sid: {
        // set the primary key for the table
        primaryKey: true,
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        autoIncrement: true,
        allowNull: false,
        unique: true
    },
    firstName: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: false
    }
}
```

GraphQl layer:

```
const StaffType = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'Staff',
  description: 'This is the GraphQl schema for the staff table',
  fields: () => ({
    sid: { type: GraphQLInt },
    firstName: { type: GraphQLString }
  })
})
```

As you can see this table has a unique key **sid**.

I'm wondering if there is way to create aliases for the different unique keys on the server so that I can use **Relay Modern** on the client side and can write queries like this one:

```
{
  node(id: "4") {
    id
    ... on Staff {
      firstName
    }
  }
}
```

Here is was Relay has to say about the fields:

> Relay’s support for object identification relies on the GraphQL server exposing object identifiers in a standardized way. In the query, the schema should provide a standard mechanism for asking for an object by ID. In the response, the schema provides a standard way of providing these IDs.

https://facebook.github.io/relay/graphql/objectidentification.htm

Comment: Where is the code that determines the GraphQL schema of your server? There, you should be able to declare the field `id` which internally resolves to `sid`.

Comment: I added the Sequelize layer. `sid` is the actual unique primary key and can't be changed to `id`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this for `StaffType` instead:

```
const StaffType = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'Staff',
  description: 'This is the GraphQl schema for the staff table',
  fields: () => ({
    id: {
      type: GraphQLID,
      resolve: (parent, args, ctx) => parent.sid
    },
    firstName: { type: GraphQLString }
  })
})
```

Here, we resolve the field `id` from an incoming GraphQL query to our internal field `sid`. Check [this tutorial](https://www.howtographql.com/graphql-js/2-a-simple-query/) for more information on GraphQL resolvers in general.

Comment: Hi Nilan, yes that might work but it's not the Relay way of doing things I found out. I might found a solution but I still need to test it.

Comment: This code is for the backend and is independent of Relay. All Relay can see is a type `StaffType` with a field `id`, which it requires. So, saying "it's not the Relay way of doing things" is surprising and I think wrong. What makes you say it?

Comment: By the way, if I'm reading [the Relay spec](https://facebook.github.io/relay/graphql/objectidentification.htm) correctly, we need the `id` field of type `ID` and not `Int`, I changed my answer accordingly.

Comment: At the moment I'm testing out this package `graphql-sequelize`. There is an explanation how to make it `Relay ready`. https://github.com/mickhansen/graphql-sequelize/blob/master/docs/relay.md. For the id I can use this function `id: globalIdField(Staff.sid)`